# Divide the image data pointed by a pointer into multiple segments

Tags: c++, cuda

I have an `unsigned char *ptr` which points to the data of a single channel image. Let say the image has 400 pixels and each pixel is of one byte. So, the `ptr` is pointing to a block of 400 bytes.

```
unsigned char *ptr = image.data;
```

I want to **divide the data into two parts** because I want to process half pixels at one stream of CUDA and another half at second stream of CUDA.

I just want to know how can I divide this data into two parts and how should I copy these two segments separately using two different CUDA streams? What should `h_half_src` and `h_second_half_src` be in the following code?

```
//Copy FIRST HALF of source image from host to device
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_half_pixels, h_half_src, dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, *strean_one);

//Copy SECOND HALF of source image from host to device
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_second_half_pixels, h_second_half_src, dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, *strean_two);
```

Comment: How about just `ptr + 200`? That will give you the second "half".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: But the original `ptr` is pointing to the whole data. So, the first call of CUDA kernel will process the whole image. I need to have another pointer may be, which tells the kernel to process only first 200 pixels. And, how would I tell that `ptr + 200` should process upto `ptr + 400`

Comment: Then just tell the kernel to process *200 bytes*? You *do* have something (argument, variable, constant, magic number) telling it to process 400 bytes, right? Just change it to 200.Then the first will process `&ptr[0]` to `&ptr[199]`, while the other processes `&ptr[200]` to `&ptr[399]`. Note the slight syntax-change, `&ptr[X]` is equal to `ptr + X` (and `ptr[X]` is equal to `*(ptr + X)`)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I have updates my question. Its not only about the kernel call. It is about the transfer from host to device also. I have to copy both the segments separately. How should I define `h_half_src ` and `h_second_half_src` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your two lines, and assuming that `dsize` is the total size (for you `400`):

```
size_t half_dsize = dsize / 2;

//Copy FIRST HALF of source image from host to device
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_half_pixels, image.data, half_dsize,
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, *strean_one);

//Copy SECOND HALF of source image from host to device
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_second_half_pixels, image.data + half_dsize, half_dsize,
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, *strean_two);
```

Comment: And, then I need to call two CUDA kernels in the normal way using the device pointers, right?